# File extraction using stand alone exe - C#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, zip, extract

I am trying to unzip a file using C# script in ssis. 
I initially used IonicZip.dll to do it as shown below, and it worked fine.

```
private string ExtractFileToDirectory(string strSourceDirectory, string strDestinationDirectory, string strFileName)
{
    string extractFileName = String.Empty;
    try
    {

        ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(Path.Combine(strSourceDirectory ,strFileName));
        Directory.CreateDirectory(strDestinationDirectory);
        foreach (ZipEntry e in zip)
        {
            e.Extract(strDestinationDirectory, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
            extractFileName = e.FileName;
        }
        zip.Dispose();
        return extractFileName;

    }
    catch 
    {
        //
    }
}
```

However, I do not have the permission to deploy the dll in the server. So I switched to 7Za.exe (the stand alone exe). Halfway through I realized it only supports 7z, cab, zip, gzip, bzip2, Z and the tar formats. The file I need to zip does not have any extension.

Is there a way to extract files with a standalone exe? I am using C# 4.0 in ssis.

My 7zip code is

```
string str7ZipPath = @"C:\Tools Use\7zip";
string str7ZipArgs = "a -tzip "+ @"""C:\Source\FileA"""+ @"  ""C:\Zip\*.*""";

ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.CreateNoWindow = false;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.FileName = str7ZipPath + "\\7za.exe";
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
psi.Arguments = str7ZipArgs;


try
{
    using (Process proc = Process.Start(psi))
    {
        proc.WaitForExit();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

Comment: Check this : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/microsoft_press/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition/

Comment: and what about already available .net resources on the FW? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I've got a bad memory with handling zip files using the NET Framework (System.IO.Packaging) and completely forgot they added a new namespace for these purposes :)

Comment: @Gusman . unfortunately ..it is available only since 4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To zip/unzip files, you can, since the .NET Framework 4.5 use the `System.Io.Compression.ZipFile` class.

However, if you can't use this .Net Framework's version, you'll have to embed a dll into your assembly :

You can add the dll to the project and set the build action to `Embedded Resource`

Then you'll have to subscribe to your application's `AssemblyResolve` event to manually load the dll from your application embedded resources.

Example :

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) => 
     {
          String resourceName = “<YourAssemblyName>.” +
               new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name + “.dll”;
          using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName)) 
          {
               Byte[] assemblyData = new Byte[stream.Length];
               stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);
               return Assembly.Load(assemblyData);
          }
     };
```

You can a more detailed explanation by Jeffrey Richter here (I leanred this trick from there): https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/microsoft_press/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition/

**OR**

You can try to use ILMerge.
It has some limitations that prevent it's une in some projects though

Comment: Thanks Sidewinder94.. I will try this out.

Comment: Can I use System.Reflection to load the dll .. Will that work ?

Comment: `System.Reflection` should be good to get the current assembly name yes . (Please note that I didn't try it out though)